# How to fetch data from Firebase Firestore by document ID - iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

How can I fetch data from Firebase Firestore, not by collection, but from current User (id).
I have this code, but when I add "document(uid)", I get error message

> "Cannot assign value of type 'DocumentReference' to type 'CollectionReference'"

```
private var collectionRef: CollectionReference!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("userInfo")  
} 

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
 
    
    collectionRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            debugPrint("error fetching docs: \(err)")
        } else {
            guard let snap = snapshot else {
                return
            }
            for document in snap.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let firstName = data[UserProfile.KEY_FIRST_NAME] as? String
                let secondName = data[UserProfile.KEY_SECOND_NAME] as? String
                
                
                self.namesLabel.text = firstName! + secondName!
                
                print(document.data())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you doing '''document(uid)'''? Just to check, the query has to follow a collection -> document collection -> document, etc, pattern. So if you just try '''Firestore.firstore().document(uid)''', that won't work

Comment: collectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("userInfo") --> here I was adding "document(uid)" but I got an error message "Cannot assign value of type 'DocumentReference' to type 'CollectionReference", so I removed

Comment: Oh, cause you defined the type of ```collectionRef``` as a ```CollectionReference```, above ```viewDidLoad```

Comment: So, how to fix that? Remove it? If I remove that, then what function should I call?

Comment: I think some clarification is needed - as is, you're reading all of the documents from a collection with `.getDocuments` which is correct. If you do this however `collectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("userInfo").document(uid)` that's now a documentRef, not a collectionRef and will present the error. Are you attempting to read a specific document or all documents? Can you clarify what you're attempting to do?

Comment: I want to read all documents by specific collection, in my case by id.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what the code in your question does. You create a referece to the userInfo collection with this `collectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("userInfo")` and then get all of the documents within that collection with this `collectionRef.getDocuments`. So great job there. What's not working? And by the way, when responding to someone in comments, to get their attention add a @ in front of their name. Like @ifF3

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the information as soon as the view fires up on `viewWillAppear`, while you wait for `viewDidLoad` to set the collection path in which the information should be retrieved from, basically do this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    collectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("userInfo")  // This line
    collectionRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            debugPrint("error fetching docs: \(err)")
        } else {
            guard let snap = snapshot else {
                return
            }
            for document in snap.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let firstName = data[UserProfile.KEY_FIRST_NAME] as? String
                let secondName = data[UserProfile.KEY_SECOND_NAME] as? String
                
                
                self.namesLabel.text = firstName! + secondName!
                
                print(document.data())
            }
        }
    }
}
```